# Stack OverFlow en Español estaba sin conexión, he perdido los progresos en mi medalla como fanático

Tags: discusión, medallas

Hoy la conexión con Stack Overflow era imposible.

He intentado conectarme durante horas sin éxito y finalmente cuando he podido conectarme he perdido el progreso (40 y pico dias) para conseguir la medalla de oro de fanático.

Es justo? Tengo solución?

Gracias a todos!!

Comment: A mi me pasó una Vez en el SO original y resumo lo que me dijeron: no se puede hacer Nada :( a ver si tienes suerte...

Comment: Como cualquier sitio web, pueden haber problemas en cualquier parte del día y ante los problemas hay varias consecuencias. No soy parte del equipo de mantenimiento de StackExchange por lo que no puedo brindar más detalles sobre el problema.

Comment: No entiendo como este caso no está contemplado... quiero decir, es normal que estas cosas pasen, todos los servicios web tienen caídas, pero debería existir algún procedimiento para restaurar los días acumulados. Sino para mucha gente será imposible conseguir ciertas medallas, y no por un tema de falta de implicación o ganas de colaborar, sino por una falla del servicio.